# Calling up different list elements in a plyr

Tags: r, plyr

I've got some code that looks like this

```
reps=128
results = llply(1:reps, function(idx){out<-single.imputation(start.data)},.parallel=TRUE)
```

start.data is a list, with values from 1-128.  How do I code this so that each plyr rep uses a different list element in `start.data`?  It would be obvious in a for loop, but its not obvious to me how to do it in plyr.  Apologies in advance if this is sort of a dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of choices (assuming start.data is a list with 128 elements)

index `start.data`

```
reps=128


results = llply(seq_len(reps), function(idx){
   out<-single.imputation(start.data[[i]])
   },.parallel=TRUE)
```

or use start.data as the `.data` argument to `llply`

```
results <- llply(start.data, function(xx) single.imputation(xx),.parallel = TRUE)
```

This could be even more simply done as

```
results <- llply(start.data, single.imputation, .parallel = TRUE)
```